# How to center text within a div

Tags: css, html, center

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="fourcol" align="center" ;="" style="float:;">
<h2 class="center" style="text-align: center;">More Mentors Announced Soon</h2>
```

The text itself is center justified, but I want it to be horizontally centered within the page. How can I do this?

This is the CSS I've been using with it

```
.fourcol, {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.762430939%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px; 
}


h2.center {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center text horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 2):

try this one.change class `fourcol to more`

```
.more {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
<div align="center" class="more">
<h2 style="text-align: center;" class="center">More Mentors Announced Soon</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/aDdge/

Just remove the width 50% line

```
h2.center {
    width: 50%; //remove this line
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/aDdge/2/

```
h2.center {
    margin-top: 34%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it still isn't working.

I've pasted the full CSS/HTML here

http://jsfiddle.net/RiverTam/sLK83/

Comment: No problem.

I'm trying to move the "More mentors announce soon" text to the center of the page.

Screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/byc59dksj/

Comment: Thank you for your continued support AlienArrays

Unfortunately the new method didn't work either. I'm starting to think it may be a fault with the original div class "fourcol". Perhaps I should create a new class?

Comment: @Kakarotto57 Well, is it correct in the fiddle that I posted ? And just not correct on your website/server?

Comment: It's correct on the Fiddle. But not on my website... Can be viewed here: www.dotforgeaccelerator.com/mentors

Comment: @Kakarotto57 please recreate the problem in a jsfiddle